# Classification of RGB images

Tags: image-classification

What is the preferred way to specify the features for image classification when the input consists of RGB images? Is it a good approach to flatten the image into a single vector (where for instance 'red' is represented by every third number) and then apply regular classification methods such as SVM or Logistic regression, or are there better ways to extract relevant information?